# Is it possible to get the data points via power bi embedded/power bi rest sdk?

Tags: powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Is it possible to get the data points from the data source directly from power bi rest api?  I looked at the API and it gives information about the dataset, but not a way to extract the data points.  There is an export feature that allows you to export it to a specific format, but I'm looking more for an api that handles paging and the sending of the data directly?

I notice that there is a Data Interact feature and a "export visual data summarised/ export visual data underlying."  However, it's not clear what they actually do.

For example, how does it summarize the data set?  Does underlying just export the data that is shown in the UI or does it show all the possible points for that datasource that the graph uses whether it's displayed or not?  What happens if the data is in the GB, how does that work?

Summary:

```
{
  "data": "This Year Sales,Chain\r\n$15658108,Fashions Direct\r\n"
}
```

Underlying:

```
{
  "data": "Chain,This Year Sales,Gross Margin This Year,Gross Margin This Year %,Gross Margin Last Year,Gross Margin Last Year %,Total Units Last Year,Total Units This Year,Avg $/Unit TY,Avg $/Unit LY,Sales Per Sq Ft,Last Year Sales,Total Sales Variance,Total Sales Variance %,Average Unit Price,Average Unit Price Last Year,Gross Margin Variance to Last Year,TotalSalesTY Goal,TotalSalesTY Status,This Year Sales Goal,This Year Sales Status\r\nFashions Direct,$15658108,$6550014,41.83 %,$6692792,40.93 %,$3464903,$3104918,$5.04,$4.72,$13.20,$16352432,($694324),-4.25 %,$5.04,$4.72,-142777.57,$16352432,0,$16352432,0\r\n"
}
```

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You're in luck :)
This is a newly released feature from the Power BI Embedded team.

You can export the data from a visual:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Export-Data

You can either export the visual currently displayed data:

```js
// Exports visual data
    visual.exportData(models.ExportDataType.Summarized, 100)
      .then(function (data) {
        Log.log(data);
      })
      .catch(function (errors) {
        Log.log(errors);
      });
```

or you can export the underlying data as using `models.ExportDataType.Underlying`

Comment: In the documenation, what does "aggregate data" refer to?

Comment: In case the dataset contains several rows that are aggregated together, by Sum, Count, Average etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-aggregates